# Spring Boot - repository field required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, sql, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am in the process of developing a Spring Boot application and came across this error when starting the server. I am not sure if I am incorrectly defining any annotations or missing any dependencies. Any help would be appreciated.

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FantasyManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FantasyManagerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

LeagueService.java:

```
@Service
public class LeagueService {

    @Autowired
    private LeagueRepository leagueRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    /**
     * Returns a list of all the leagues in the database 
     * @return List<League>
     */
    public List<League> getAllLeagues(){
        List<League> leagues = new ArrayList<>();
        leagueRepository.findAll()
        .forEach(leagues::add);
        return leagues;
    }

    /**
     * Find details for a particular League
     * @param leagueId
     * @return League
     */
    public League getLeagueById(long leagueId){
        return leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId);
    }

    /**
     * Find the leagueSettings for a particular League  
     * @param leagueId
     * @return LeagueSettings
     */
    public LeagueSettings getLeagueSettingsById(long leagueId){
        return leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId).getLeagueSettings();
    }


    /**
     * Returns a list of all the Team's in the League
     * @param leagueId
     * @return List<Team>
     */
    public List<Team> getTeamsInLeague(long leagueId){
        List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
        leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId).getTeams()
        .forEach(teams::add);
        return teams;

    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of all the Player's in the League
     * @param leagueId
     * @return List<Player>
     */
    public List<Player> getPlayersInLeague(long leagueId){
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId).getPlayers()
        .forEach(players::add);
        return players;     
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of all the User's in the League
     * @param leagueId
     * @return List<User>
     */
    public List<User> getUsersInLeague(long leagueId){
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId).getUsers()
        .forEach(users::add);
        return users;       
    }


    /**
     * Add League to database
     * @param league
     */
    public void addLeague(League league){
        leagueRepository.save(league);
    }

    /**
     * Assign LeagueSettings for a League
     * @param userId
     * @param leagueSettings
     */
    public void assignLeagueSettings(long leagueId, LeagueSettings leagueSettings){
        League league = leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId);
        league.setLeagueSettings(leagueSettings);
        leagueRepository.save(league);  
    }

    /**
     * Assign a Player to a League and vice versa
     * @param leagueId
     * @param playerId
     */
    public void assignPlayerToLeague(long leagueId, long playerId){
        //Find the league and player from the database
        League league = leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId);
        Player player = playerRepository.findOne(playerId);

        //Get the players that the league already has
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players = league.getPlayers();

        //Get the leagues that the player is part of
        List<League> leagues = new ArrayList<>();
        leagues = player.getLeagues();

        //Assign player to this league and vice versa
        leagues.add(league);
        players.add(player);
        league.setPlayers(players);
        player.setLeagues(leagues);

        //Update changes in database
        playerRepository.save(player);
        leagueRepository.save(league);
    }

    /**
     * Assign a Team to a League and vice versa
     * @param leagueId
     * @param teamId
     */
    public void assignTeamToLeague(long leagueId, long teamId){
        //Find the league and player from the database
        League league = leagueRepository.findOne(leagueId);
        Team team = teamRepository.findOne(teamId);

        //Get the teams that are already in the league
        List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
        teams = league.getTeams();

        //Assign team to this league and vice versa
        teams.add(team);
        league.setTeams(teams);
        team.setLeague(league);

        //Update changes in database
        teamRepository.save(team);
        leagueRepository.save(league);
    }


    /**
     * Edit the details for a particular League
     * @param league
     */
    public void updateLeague(League league, long leagueId){
        leagueRepository.save(league);
    }


    /**
     * Delete the League from the database
     * @param leagueId
     */
    public void deleteLeague(long leagueId){
        leagueRepository.delete(leagueId);
    }

}
```

LeagueRepository.java

```
public interface LeagueRepository extends CrudRepository<League, Long> {

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dheeraj</groupId>
    <artifactId>fantasy-manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>fantasy-manager</name>
    <description>Fantasy Manager Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field leagueRepository in com.dheeraj.service.LeagueService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have JPA autoconfiguration running. Make sure you have the starter and a database connection.

Comment: @chrylis - How do I get a JPA autoconfiguration running? I have established a connection to mysql database in application.properties

Comment: You have mismatched Hibernate dependencies. Just drop the version numbers and let Boot manage them.

Answer (score 35):

**spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** will pull in all the hibernate dependencies you need.  Using spring boot release 1.5.1, it will pull in **hibernate-core:5.0.11** and **hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.11**.  In addition to being unnecessary, your hibernate dependency versions are mismatched which is what I'm guessing is causing the error.

Try removing these dependencies from your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have a similar error, and I did include hibernate myself. However, according to `mvn dependency:tree` I have `spring-boot:jar:2.0.3.` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.3.` includes only `hibernate-core` but not `hibernate-entitymanager`.

Comment: @NicCottrell Cottrell I am running into same issue with Spring Boot 2.0.3. I was wondering how you fixed it for yourself?

Comment: @NicCottrell ,@Ajay kumar ;i am on the same issue and tried all possible solutions but no luck.please let me know how did you take it forward?

Answer (score 13):

## Try these dependencies

```xml
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>   
  <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

## instead of:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate-core 5.2.0 have problem with Spring Data JPA while process collection. 
Hibernate-core 5.2.1 and above is ok with Spring Data JPA when you use Spring Data JPA.

From hibernate onwards 5.2.0. hibernate-entitymanager is no longer needed.

**So try to change:**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**To this version:**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
 <version> 5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be due to version mismatch. Problem can be solve by specifying the dependency like this (since version is not mentioned, its auto managed)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your dependencies from

- ~/.m2/repository (Linux)
- C:/Users/**your_user**/.m2/repository (Windows)

and further updating your project dependencies either through your IDE's **update dependencies** functionality, or by running **mvn install** from your project's folder.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the problem again. What I did is to change pom dependecy.

From **spring-data-jpa**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**No extra hibernate related dependency.**

Answer (score 1):

For those having two datasources, just add @Primary at one of the datasources.