# Error: Required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have problem with configuration in basic project with Spring Boot and Hibernate.
Console showed me: *Required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.*
I tried many tips from here but none work good for me.
Can anyone help me with this?

This is my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is my MainController:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MainController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainController.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my UserController:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping("/tbs/login")
    public boolean logIn(@RequestBody(required = false) User user) {
        Boolean userExist = false;
        User user = userDao.checkIfExistByEmail(user.getEmail());
        return user != null ? true : false ;
    }
}
```

This is my UserDao:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

   @Query("SELECT u FROM user WHERE u.email = ?1")
   User checkIfExistByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - repository field required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182426/spring-boot-repository-field-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that)

Comment: Use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, you dont need hibernate separately.